# Prove the inequality that the function f is differentiable and the derivative is Lipschitz continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, lipschitz-functions

**Problem:** If function $f$ defined on $\mathbb R$ is differentiable, its derivative is Lipschitz continuous and $f(0)=0$.

Show that exists constant $C$ such that
$$ |f(a)-f(b)-f(c)+f(d)| \le C|a-b-c+d|+C|a-b|(|a-c|+|b-d|).$$
I considered this problem for several days, but I could not prove it. I hope you can give me some suggestions.

My question comes from an analysis conclusion used in the proof of the uniqueness of the solution in this article "Stochastic heat equation with rough dependence in space" written by Yaozhong Hu. The author says that the conclusion holds on the rectangular increments of $f$. At present, I only proved that the situation $a,b,c=a+h,d=b+h$, where I posted as an answer.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What were your ideas that didn't work out? Or some thoughts you had? This website is for helping solve problems not for solving them for you. You will see that more people will answer if you put some effort into it.

Answer (score 1):

I only proved that the situation $a, b, c=a+h, d=b+h$.

**Proof**. If $c=a+h, d=b+h, a,b,h\in \mathbb R$. Then
$$|f(a)-f(b)-f(c)+f(d)|=|f(a)-f(b)-f(a+h)+f(b+h)|,$$
Let $$g(t)=f(b+th)-f(a+th),$$
then
$$|f(a)-f(b)-f(a+h)+f(b+h)|=|g(1)-g(0)|=|f'(b+\theta h)h-f'(a+\theta h)h|,$$
by using the Lipschitz continuous of $f'$, then
$$|f(a)-f(b)-f(a+h)+f(b+h)|\le C|a-b||h|.$$